# Limit CPU usage of background process if system is busy

Tags: cpu-usage, limit, cpulimit

At the moment I do the following: When I see that the system load of my Ubuntu server is high, I get the PIDs of specific currently running background processes and start cpulimit with the PID. When the system load gets lower, I kill cpulimit, so that the background processes can run faster. When the load is still too high, I also kill cpulimit and start it again with a lower limit for the process.

I repeat this until the background processes are done after a few hours. But it gets very annoying to do this manually every day, so I would like to know if there is a way to automate this.

Comment: Have you already answered the question: "How should a system distinguish between foreground and background processes on a server?" If so, please add this to your question.

Comment: `man 1 nice`, `man 1 renice`, `man 1 chrt`.

Comment: Also, how do you determine that system is busy? How do you define a "busy system"?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try running "background" processes using `nice -20`.

That won't affect their performance if they are the only ones running but if you have foreground tasks, those will run faster as they are not "niced".